# Database password expiry date is reached but account status is open

Tags: sql, security, oracle11g

I was looking into oracle database 11gR2 to verify the users who's days to expire comes to below 7 days and i have noticed few of the users expiry date are today but their account status is in open instead of Expired(Grace) and some users which passed the expiry date but still in open status.

```
USERNAME                       ACCOUNT_STATUS                   EXPIRY_DA PROFILE
------------------------------ -------------------------------- --------- ------------------------------
SYSTEM                         OPEN                             27-JAN-16 DEFAULT
SYS                            OPEN                             28-DEC-14 DEFAULT
ERERD                          OPEN                             18-JAN-16 DEFAULT
ERFWSE                         OPEN                             04-DEC-14 DEFAULT
SERFW                          OPEN                             03-AUG-15 DEFAULT
DERSZFERSS                     OPEN                             04-DEC-14 DEFAULT
```

My query is not helping in this case to find the users whose account will be expired. Can anyone help me with modifing the query such a way that it will only list out the users and their accounts genuinely will expiry by number of days?

```
select username, account_status, trunc(expiry_date-sysdate) days_to_expire
from dba_users
where  expiry_date is not null and trunc(expiry_date-sysdate) >= 0;
```

### Update

```
SQL> select * from dba_profiles where profile = 'DEFAULT' and resource_name = 'PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME';

PROFILE                        RESOURCE_NAME                    RESOURCE LIMIT
------------------------------ -------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------------------
DEFAULT                        PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME               PASSWORD 180
```

Comment: What is the type of `EXPIRY_DATE`?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is allright.

Password expiration date and account status are different things.

You can have an expired password user that will stay in open status while you try to connect to it.
If you have permission to change password you can then set a new password,
otherwise the user will be locked.

This means that if you're connecting with an application and the application doesn't check password expiration date the user will be locked
and if there isn't a connection the user will stay open.

Answer (score 1):

There is no process that goes through accounts to reset their status vis a vis expiry date. The next time the user logs in the status will be updated accordingly
~~~H Otati